# InteliJ IDEA - Run code or debug not working ( Greyed out)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

so i have this problem and cannot find solution on my own. I believe i have set up IDEA correctly , because when i start a new project and use the provided template i can add my own code and run it fine!

However the problem happens when i am trying to open some example code from tutorials that are compiled in packages ( com.exmaple.java) e.g of tutorial material directory: C:\Users\Edgar\Desktop\Ex_Files_JavaEssT_Q32015\Exercise Files\Ch04\04_03\Currency\src\com\example\java.

I have tried opening on the curency part , the src part and the files themselves but nothing works and i cannot run code of these tutorials. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5m5F.jpg) for my Idea.

Comment: Create a new java project from a template and you will see what was wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you should mark the "src" directory as Sources Root.
Just right click the "src" directory, choose Mark Directory as -> Sources Root

[The Context menu to mark the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgZpt.png)